# X86 assembly, how memory operation work?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to understand what happen when an assembly statement is read by the processor. The machine is Intel 8088 and the statement is

```
MOV AX, [100]
```

Assuming the data code register (CS) has the value of `0xA1B2` (16-bit), does the assembly line says that Instruction Pointer (IP)  has the value of `100`? Is that hex or decimal?

Assuming that the value inside [] is decimal, I will write `100 = 0x64`. Then the physical address is calculated by

```
A1B20 + 64 = A1B84
```

So the processor put the `0xA1B84` on the address bus (which is 20-bit wide). Since the 8088 reads two bytes, it will put the content of `0xA1B84` and `0xA1B85` on the data bus and deliver it to the processor. Is the following figure correct? The result is `1000,0110,0011,1010` (note the MSB and LSB)

```
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |    <--   0x0A1B2 (start of CS)
+-------------------+
|                   |   
//                 //   
|                   |   
+-------------------+
| 0011     1010     |    <--   0xA1B84
+-------------------+
| 1000     0110     |
+-------------------+
| 0101     1001     |    <--   0xA1B86
+-------------------+
|                   |
//                 //
|                   |
```

Another problem is that a programmer may want to use an odd offset. For example

```
MOV AX, [101]
```

Then the physical address will be `A1B20 + 65 = A1B85`. Then reading two bytes, Will read `1000,0110,0101,1001` (according to the above figure) and a 16-bit content from 0xA1B86. How than is justified? What is *word boundary* then? I mixed them up!

Comment: Have you read any tutorials or books describing x86 assembly language and/or x86 architecture? With `mov ax, [100]`, the IP is an *instruction pointer*, so `100` is not in the IP, since that's data. In this case, address `100` decimal (as determined by the *assembler* you are using) is read from the *data segment* which is in the DS register. In other words, if the `DS` contains `0x1000`, then this will read the word from location `(0x1000 * 16) + 100(d)` or address `0x10064` and put that result into `AX`. If you're wondering what `* 16` is about, read up on the x86 architecture.

Comment: @mahmood whether the machine is Intel 8088 or 8086 isn't relevant to the question. It doesn't matter if the data arrives as two 8-bit values or as one 16-bit value.

Comment: @mahmood - The x86 family of processors will read your data even if you use an unaligned address. Possibly by issuing more than one read, and discarding some bytes. For the 8088 it doesn't matter much, as it reads single bytes anyway.

Comment: we can assume 100 is decimal here, but understand that assembly language is defined by the assembler, and no reason to assume that from one assembler to the next the same default assumption is used.  the only thing that has to be consistent from one assembly language to the next for the same target, is the machine code matches the target.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction `MOV AX, [100]` has no effect on the IP register (other than the fact that IP updated to point to the following instruction after executing it as normal). The memory reference `[100]` is relative to the DS register not the CS register.

Reading a 16-bit value from an odd address works the same as from an even address. The first byte becomes the lower order byte of the value, the second byte becomes the higher order byte of the value.

Since the displacement in memory operands is 16 bits wide a number in the range of 0-65535 can be used. An array of up to 65536 bytes in size can accessed directly using a memory operand like this, but it's possible to access larger arrays using segment arithmetic and loading a new segment value.

Comment: Yes, I mixed up things.... [] is not related to CS:IP. Let me update the post and I will ask more since the odd/even addresses have not been resolved for me yet.

Comment: @mahmood You're not allowed to change your question so that it would invalidate answers by turning it into a different question.

Comment: OK I left that intact. Please note the last line in my question.

Comment: @mahmood The second paragraph in most post above answers the last line in your question. If you don't understand it, it would help to know what you don't understand about it. Do you know what lower order and higher order means?